# If statement only iterating over 1st line

Tags: python-2.7

When printing row in a csv file, how do you get it to iterate over the entire csv instead of one line at a time when performing an if statement?  For example:

```
import csv
nameid = raw_input("ID please")
with open('cards.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        row = list(row)
        if nameid == row[0]:
            print row
        else:
            print "sorry"
```

with this csv:

```
101,8
102,10
103,5
104,0
```

will use only the first line, then the second line, and so on, giving me a false statement 3 out of 4 times.  So if I search for "102" in my raw_input, it will print:

```
"sorry"
['102', '10']
"sorry"
"sorry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually very close to your intended functionality. You don't want to print "sorry" for every line that doesn't match, so you don't want that `else` block where it is. But you do want to print "sorry" if nothing at all in the file matches. As it turns out, you can just scoot that `else` block over one level to the left and have it correspond to the `for` block instead of the `if`. You'll also need one extra line:

```
import csv
nameid = raw_input("ID please")
with open('cards.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        row = list(row)
        if nameid == row[0]:
            print row
            break
    else:
        print "sorry"
```

Now the `else` block is only triggered if the `for` block runs to completion (more info on this syntax [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html)). To make sure it only runs to completion if there are no matches, add the `break` to immediately exit the loop when you see a match.

Comment: That was it!  I have been searching days for this info, thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not giving you a false statement each time. You are iterating through the csv and checking every row's first element against the input. If it doesn't match, you print 'sorry'. If it does, you print the row.

If you want to only print a 'sorry' message if no matches are found, get rid of your else clause. Instead, set a boolean flag that gets initialized as false and only set to true when a match is found. After your iteration is complete, only print the 'sorry' message if the boolean is still false.